# SQL get consecutive days ignoring weekend

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with following format:

```
ID    ID1    ID2    DATE

1      1      1     2018-03-01     
2      1      1     2018-03-02
3      1      1     2018-03-05
4      1      1     2018-03-06
5      1      1     2018-03-07
6      2      2     2018-03-05
7      2      2     2018-03-05 
8      2      2     2018-03-06
9      2      2     2018-03-07
10     2      2     2018-03-08
```

From this table I have to get all records where `ID1` and `ID2` are the same in that column and where `DATE` is 5 consecutive work days (5 dates in a row, ignoring missing dates for Saturday/Sunday; ignore holidays).

I have really no idea how to achieve this. I did search around, but couldn't find anything that helped me. So my question is, how can I achieve following output?

```
ID    ID1    ID2    DATE

1      1      1     2018-03-01     
2      1      1     2018-03-02
3      1      1     2018-03-05
4      1      1     2018-03-06
5      1      1     2018-03-07
```

---

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e0b85) to mess around

Comment: Working days are a nebulous concept, not only because of weekends but also because of holidays.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer But how do you know if for example there is a 3 days gap, but that was Easter Monday, or there is a 2 days gap, but that was Christmas on week days. What Gordon wants to say is that you have to specify working days more precisely. Having a table listing them, or having a calendar table with a 'IsWorkingDay' column in it might do the trick, from that it is just a simple searching for islands script.

Comment: @Pred Ahhh yeah you right. I just understood it wrong. Sadly I don't have a table which lists such days. Therefore I would totally ignore them

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have no duplicates and work is *only* on weekdays, then there is a simplish solution for this particular case.  We can identify the date 4 rows ahead.  For a complete week, it is either 4 days ahead or 6 days ahead:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lead(dat, 4) over (order by id2, dat) as dat_4
      from t
     ) t
where datediff(day, dat, dat_4) in (4, 6);
```

This happens to work because you are looking for a complete week.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e0b85/28) is the SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Can it be changed so that I get the 5 rows printed instead of just 1? Also I would prefer a solution without `LEAD` (used the wrong tag for database system)

Answer (score 1):

```
select t.* from 
(select id1,id2,count(distinct dat) count from t 
group by id1,id2
having count(distinct dat)=5) t1 right join 
t
on t.id1=t1.id1 and t.id2=t1.id2
where count=5
```

Check this-

Dates of Two weeks with 10 valid dates
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/76556/1

Dates of Two weeks with 10 non-unique dates
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b4299/1

and

Dates of Two weeks with less than 10 but unique
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f16cb/1

Comment: Please note that ID1 and ID2 do not have to be equals. In the example data ID2 could have any value as long as it is continuous between multiple records

Comment: Seems the right  and required answer as you stated in question  `I have to get all records where ID1 and ID2 are the same in that column`

Comment: @Sami With that I mean that ID1 should be the same within each set as well as ID2 (which can be different from ID1)

Comment: @XtremeBaumer just remove id1=id2 in where clause ,i have edited the answer.Hope this solves

Comment: Nearly what I need. I adapted it to my data and it even selects data with a 5 days gap which is not what I want. Also if I add 2 more rows, it doesn't work at all. [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c2cf9/4)

Comment: if you want result with 5 days gap you have to use count()>5 else count()=5,
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c2cf9/7

Answer (score 1):

This query is very verbose without LEAD or LAG and it is the best I could do on my lunch break. You can probably improve on it given the time.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    ID INT,
    ID1 INT,
    ID2 INT,
    TheDate DATETIME
)
INSERT @T SELECT 1,1,1,'03/01/2018'
INSERT @T SELECT 2,1,1,'03/02/2018'
INSERT @T SELECT 3,1,1,'03/05/2018'

INSERT @T SELECT 4,1,1,'03/06/2018'
INSERT @T SELECT 5,1,1,'03/07/2018'
--INSERT @T SELECT 5,1,1,'03/09/2018'
INSERT @T SELECT 6,2,2,'03/02/2018'
INSERT @T SELECT 7,2,2,'03/05/2018'
INSERT @T SELECT 8,2,2,'03/05/2018'
--INSERT @T SELECT 9,2,2,'03/06/2018'
INSERT @T SELECT 10,2,2,'03/07/2018'
INSERT @T SELECT 11,2,2,'03/08/2018'
INSERT @T SELECT 12,2,2,'03/15/2018'

INSERT @T SELECT 13,1,1,'04/01/2018'
INSERT @T SELECT 14,1,1,'04/02/2018'
INSERT @T SELECT 15,1,1,'04/05/2018'

--SELECT * FROM @T

DECLARE @LowDate DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY,-1,(SELECT MIN(TheDate) FROM @T))
DECLARE @HighDate DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY,1,(SELECT MAX(TheDate) FROM @T))
DECLARE @DaysThreshold INT = 5
;
WITH Dates AS
(
  SELECT DateValue=@LowDate
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  DateValue + 1 FROM    Dates   
  WHERE   DateValue + 1 < @HighDate  
),
Joined AS
(
    SELECT * FROM Dates LEFT OUTER JOIN  @T T ON T.TheDate=Dates.DateValue 
),
Calculations AS
(
    SELECT 
        ID=MAX(J1.ID),
        J1.ID1,J1.ID2,
        J1.TheDate,
        LastDate=MAX(J2.TheDate), 
        LastDateWasWeekend = CASE WHEN ((DATEPART(DW,DATEADD(DAY,-1,J1.TheDate) ) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) NOT IN (0, 1) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, 
        Offset =  DATEDIFF(DAY,MAX(J2.TheDate),J1.TheDate)  
    FROM 
        Joined J1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Joined J2 ON J2.ID1=J1.ID1 AND J2.ID2=J1.ID2 AND J2.TheDate<J1.TheDate
    WHERE
        NOT J1.ID IS NULL
    GROUP BY J1.ID1,J1.ID2,J1.TheDate
)
,FindValid AS
(
    SELECT
        ID,ID1,ID2,TheDate,
        IsValid=CASE 
            WHEN LastDate=TheDate THEN 0
            WHEN LastDate IS NULL THEN 1
            WHEN Offset=1 THEN 1
            WHEN Offset>3 THEN 0
            WHEN Offset<=3 THEN 
                LastDateWasWeekend
            END
    FROM 
        Calculations
    UNION 
    SELECT DISTINCT ID=NULL,ID1,ID2, TheDate=@HighDate,IsValid=0 FROM @T

),
FindMax As
(
    SELECT 
        This.ID,This.ID1,This.ID2,This.TheDate,MaxRange=MIN(Next.TheDate)
    FROM 
        FindValid This
    LEFT OUTER JOIN FindValid Next ON Next.ID2=This.ID2 AND Next.ID1=This.ID1 AND This.TheDate<Next.TheDate AND Next.IsValid=0 
    GROUP BY 
        This.ID,This.ID1,This.ID2,This.TheDate
),
FindMin AS
(
    SELECT 
        This.ID,This.ID1,This.ID2,This.TheDate,This.MaxRange,MinRange=MIN(Next.TheDate) 
    FROM 
        FindMax This
        LEFT OUTER JOIN FindMax Next ON Next.ID2=This.ID2 AND Next.ID1=This.ID1 AND This.TheDate<Next.MaxRange-- AND Next.IsValid=0 OR Next.TheDate IS NULL 
    GROUP BY 
        This.ID,This.ID1,This.ID2,This.TheDate,This.MaxRange
)
,Final AS
(
SELECT 
    ID1,ID2,MinRange,MaxRange,SequentialCount=COUNT(*) 
FROM
    FindMin
GROUP BY
    ID1,ID2,MinRange,MaxRange    

)

SELECT 
    T.ID,
    T.ID1,
    T.ID2,
    T.TheDate 
FROM @T T 
    INNER JOIN Final ON T.TheDate>= Final.MinRange AND T.TheDate < Final.MaxRange AND T.ID1=Final.ID1 AND T.ID2=Final.ID2
WHERE
    SequentialCount>=@DaysThreshold
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```